# grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have removed grub and now need to install it again however I am having the following issues when trying to install.

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.
```

My disks

```
hutber@hutber:~$ lsblk /dev/nvme*
lsblk: /dev/nvme0: not a block device
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 918.3G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  12.7G  0 part 
nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
nvme0n1p2   259:2    0 918.3G  0 part /
nvme0n1p3   259:3    0  12.7G  0 part
```

Is there a simple way for me to install grub again?

Trying on my nvme disk:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: attempt to read or write outside of disk `hostdisk//dev/nvme0'.
```

#### Edit

It appears my sda is taken up by an external drive I have:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda "print free"
Model: ATA ST8000AS0002-1NA (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 8002GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
        134MB   135MB   1031kB  Free Space
 2      135MB   8002GB  8001GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
        8002GB  8002GB  335kB   Free Space
```

Comment: You are using the wrong grub for an efi installation.  grub-pc is for legacy, grub-efi is for UEFI installs.  If you really want a legacy install, you need to supply an explicit 2M raw grub-bios partition to hold code, necessary on a gpt dsk since that code cannot fit between the partitions like on a DOS partitioned disk.

Comment: Thanks, no I absolutely do not :) I would be very happy to install efi. I guess I will just `sudo apt install grub-efi` would do the trick. I shall give it a whirl